# magento admin assert issue

Tags: magento, admin, assert

> Error in file: "/home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_role' already exists

**Trace:**

```
#0 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.1.1')
#2 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.1.1')
#3 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/siddharth/iphp/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to your localhost or mysql on your server and delete the table that gives error...

2) Clear cookies and refresh that page again

3) Ater 2nd step if same error persist then close the browser and restart it...this will delete all cookies and cache and then hit the url again... do these steps for all errors that come... after this successful completion will be done...